# Can I override the behaviour of opportunitylineitemschedule in a Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, standard-objects

[image]Can any one help me out with this requirement?

I need to create a custom object as schedule and override the behaviour of a standard object (opportunitylineitemschedule) in a visualforce page, by populating the custom fields. Any help is very much appreciated.

I would like to create this page for a custom object through Visual force page and make this Vf page as a related list to opportunitylineitem.

Comment: So you want to populate fields in the custom object as the standard object fields would be without the override?

Comment: @LaceySnr:PFA ScreenShot .I would like to create this page for a custom object through Visual force page and make this Vf page as a related list to opportunitylineitem.

Comment: @nikkey You cannot make a VF page a related list. Also, what have you tried so far and where are you having trouble. You will get more answers if you do some of the work yourself and ask specific questions where you are getting stuck.

Comment: @Eric:Thanks for your reply.I mean we do have an option in pagelayout for the visual force pages to be appeared in the detail page